# the mini js tool library

Tags: javascript, node.js, library

I am a newbie js "developer" and for practice, I created a tiny (8 methods) JavaScript library. I need you to give me feedback **"should I keep expanding my library or switch to something else"** and how do I improve the code quality?

***full code:***

```js
function isObject(val) {
      if (val === null) { return false;}
      return ( (typeof val === 'function') || (typeof val === 'object') );
  }
  
function isDate(value) {
      switch (typeof value) {
          case 'number':
              return true;
          case 'string':
              return !isNaN(Date.parse(value));
          case 'object':
              if (value instanceof Date) {
                  return !isNaN(value.getTime());
              }
          default:
              return false;
      }
  }
  
function isEmptyOrOnlySpacesString(str) {
      return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
  }
  
function getTimeZone() {
      return Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  }
  
function doesObjectHaveEmptyProperties(obj) {
    let emptyKeys = [];
          for(let key in obj) {
          if(obj[key] === "") {
             emptyKeys.push(key + " is empty.\n");
          }
            
      }
    return emptyKeys.join('') + ' others keys are filled';
  }

function isSorted (arr){
  return arr.every((a,b,c) => !b || c[b-1] <= a);
}

function shuffleArray (arr){
  let len = arr.length;
  while (len) {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * len--);
    [arr[len], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[len]];
  }
  return arr;
}

function generateRandomIntArr(len, upTo){
  return Array.from({ length: len }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * upTo));
}
```

Also you can visit my [github repo](https://github.com/delaklo/js-tools-base)

***thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a short review;

- You may want to check out the lodash library, the implementation of [isObject](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L11743) there is

  ```
  function isObject(value) {
    var type = typeof value;
    return value != null && (type == 'object' || type == 'function');
  }
  ```

  - It does spell out completely `value`, which is better for readability
  - It does not repeat typeof value, but stores it in a temp value (would have gone for `const` here though)
  - It has one exit statement which seems cleaner
- isDate returns true for `37`, it feels wrong. I would try to parse numbers as well. Furthermore the functional name lies a bit, it does not check whether value is a date, but whether it can be converted to a date.
- I prefer `list` more than `arr`, it reads better as a whole word
- `arr.every((a,b,c)` -> those variable names are not good. `every` is not that common. I would if you insist on 1 letter variables go for v,i,l/a (value, index, list/array)
- I would expect `shuffleArray` to create a new shuffled list, not to shuffle in place.
- `let emptyKeys` could be `const`

Comment: Also see the ramda library https://stackoverflow.com/a/71403954/1614973